# Can't reference class buttons from methods

Tags: java, android

I declare a button in the Main Activity, but get NullObjectReference when I run the app. No matter where I try to move the declaration (outside of the class, inside the onCreate method, etc.), it redlines either the declaration or the button reference. I see posts recommending status versus non-static classes/methods, but I'm new to OOP and not exactly sure how to implement that. Can anyone tell me what I'm doing wrong?

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    …
    // Declare button in the MainActivity 
    Button btnWrong = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btnWrong);
    ...

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {

    // WHEN USER TAPS ITEMS ON APPBAR
    switch (item.getItemId())  {
        case R.id.mnuLoad:  // If use taps "Load"
            final Dialog dialog = new Dialog(MainActivity.this); /
    …

btnLoad.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()  {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        deckNumber = deckPicker.getValue();
        if …        }
        dialog.dismiss();
        btnWrong.setEnabled(true); // Trying to reference the button here
```

Comment: Your findViewById and setOnClickListener code should be in onCreate. Please include the onCreate code in your question so we have a better idea what you're doing wrong

Answer (score 0):

You have to do this:

outside `onCreate()`  (under public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity)

```
Button btnWrong; //Declare button as private
```

in `onCreate()`

```
btnWrong = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btnWrong);
```

Now you can use `btnWrong` anywhere in its class

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    // Declare as class field
    Button btnWrong;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.YOUR_LAYOUT_XML);

        btnWrong = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btnWrong);
    }
    ....
}
```